# Внести данные в таблицу Access через Delphi

Tags: delphi, база-данных, access

Как внести данные в таблицу используя значения `Edit1` и `Edit2`? При этом внести их нужно в поля Базы Данных Access `StudentID` и `StudentName`, где `TeacherID` равен значению из `Edit3`.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO GradeTable (StudentID, StudentName) VALUES (ID, Name);');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value := Trim(Edit2.Text);
```

Пробовал делать так, но это лишь вводит данные в новую строку, а мне нужно чтобы добавляло в уже существующую, где `TeacherID = Edit3.Text`.

Comment: Ну а что Вы хотите получить используя Insert?? Используйте Update вместо Insert и будет обновляться нужная Вам строка

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE GradeTable
SET StudentID = :param1, StudentName = :param2
WHERE TeacherID = :param3;
```